# Creating a titled Google Sheets results in a "Proto field" error when using the NodeJs client library

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to create a Google Spreadsheet using a NodeJs backend and the Google Sheets v4 API.
I was following the [`spreadsheets.create` tutorial](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) in documentation. However, when I create the file using some specified properties, I always get the following error:

> Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "title" at 'spreadsheet.properties': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.

In the tutorial nothing, is mentioned about a "Proto" field. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Creating the file does work, if I don't specify properties. However the properties are used to set a name for the file and the sheets, so I do need a way to set this metadata.

Here is the request I am sending with the properties included:

```
const request = {
  auth,
  resource: {
    properties: {
      title: name,
    },
    sheets: [
      {
        properties: {
          title: 'General',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: It seems that your request body is correct. So can you provide your script for requesting it? I think that it will help users think of your solution.

Comment: i'm assuming the request is actually `{auth: authClient, properties: {....` and you just missed including the authClient bit in your transcription, right?